# Issue - Importing a csv file to Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, import, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a csv file called movimi.csv that has 37781 records, but when i do the query to import on mysql workbench, it only imports 663 lines.

And it doesn't show any error. On the output says:

> "662 row(s) affected
>   Records: 37781 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 37119 Warnings: 0"

And the query is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\JcVelez_Workspace\\Jorge\\MOVIMI.csv' 
INTO TABLE empresa.movimi 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Any solution to this?

pd: sorry for my english =)

Answer (score 0):

Solved

The issue was that my table has the column "codigo" as primary key, so, when you use load data local infile, it ignores the duplicate data.

Just, i didn't use primary key and it works.